# Same Formula for Different Rows

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have an item expense sheet to keep track of things I sell and my total profits for each item.
Right now I been copying and pasting the formula and changing the numbers for the corresponding row its in.

Example:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item | Sale Price | Shipping | Fee | Total |
| Cookies | 15 | 3 | 2 | Formula |
| Apples | 20 | 5 | 2 | Formula |

Formula =SUM(B3-C3-D3)

I would like to use the same formula without having to edit the numbers for the corresponding row its in.

Is there a wildcard or a way to define to use the number of the row its in, so I could do something like =SUM(B#-C#-D#)

Comment: Are you in google-sheet or Excel.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one array formula for the entire column E, and then you don't have to copy the formula every time you add new rows

Clear the range `E2:E` and put this formula in cell `E2`

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", B2:B-C2:C-D2:D, ))`

Answer (score 0):

You can drag formula to other cell below it. Formula will automatically change the cell address.
If you have `=SUM(B3-C3-D3)` will change `=SUM(B4-C4-D4)` etc

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data shown in your post, delete everything from Column E (including the header) and place the following formula in E1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Total"; IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(B2:D)),0,B2:D),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B:D),1,1,0)))})`

This single formula will produce the header and all results for the column, no matter how many rows of data you add.

`MMULT` is a difficult function to explain, since it deals with matrix multiplication — a math concept not many people are familiar with. But I'll attach an image I made that gives a graphic representation. In short, `MMULT` multiplies every element of every row of one matrix by every element of every column of a second matrix.  Since the `SEQUENCE` section I included will be composed of all only the number 1 stacked three high, and since any number multiplied by itself is itself, this allows for row-by-row addition of all numbers.

[image]